# Loading Rdlc report from Network folder-Workgroup Environment

Tags: c#, rdlc

I had a Windows form with a report viewer . I had created a rdlc report which uses a typed dataset as datasource.The report was created in VS2013 and the intial location was in the application folder at the design and testing stage.Now I need to deploy the application to the users and want to put the folder in a Network Shared folder which is open to all workgroup users.

I write the code like this and this was working perfectly when report source is inside the application folder and the source is added at designer

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shipitdata dta = new Shipitdata();
            ShipitdataTableAdapters.LinePlanTableAdapter adapt = new LinePlanTableAdapter();
            DataTable dt = adapt.GetData();
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Shipitdata", dt);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
          //  loadreport();
        }
```

Now  I need to load the report from the shared folder so I write the code as below

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shipitdata dta = new Shipitdata();
            ShipitdataTableAdapters.LinePlanTableAdapter adapt = new LinePlanTableAdapter();
            DataTable dt = adapt.GetData();
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Shipitdata", dt);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

             reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

            reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"\\sreenath-it\HRMSERVER\Reports_ATCHRM\Report1.rdlc";
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("sreenath", "******", "atraco");
            reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials  = cred;

            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

But When the form loads I am not getting any data in the report . The report viewer is blank without any data do anyone have a clue

Comment: how about embedding the report in application assembly?

Comment: Also how are you deploying the application? is it by click once?

Comment: this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = " @"\\sreenath-it\HRMSERVER\Reports_ATCHRM\Report1.rdlc";

Comment: Also previously I was just giving the exe i got after debuging the project.But now I am thinking of clickonce